# Spring-data-jpa:2.0.3 Compatible Spring Version

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

I have just upgraded spring-data-jpa from version 1.11.13 to 2.0.8. However, now I am getting AbstractMethodError. I am suspecting that the new version of spring-data-jpa is not compatible with current spring version I am using, that is 4.2.4. I even tried upgrading to 5.0.3 but it didn't work.
Can anyone please help?

Comment: If only that was documented. Oh wait: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/2.0.8.RELEASE/reference/html/#dependencies.spring-framework

Answer (score 0):

JB Nizet already pointed you to the documentation where you find that information. While the version you picked isn't listed as compatible its only a Minor release behind so I don't think this explains the `AbstractMethodError`. What the exact reason for that is would require at least a full stack trace and all the Spring related dependencies you are using.

But I have the impression that you are doing something that makes your life unnecessary hard. 
Assuming you are using Maven or something similar, only specify the dependency and version of Spring Data JPA. 
Maven will pull the proper version of Spring to go with that.

If you have multiple dependencies on Spring libraries only specify those where nothing but your code depends on. 
Again Maven will do it's best to pull down the correct version of other libraries like Spring Framework.

At this point there might be conflicts which you can then analyse using [`mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/resolving-conflicts-using-the-dependency-tree.html).