# Update Spring 3 to 4. JPA

Tags: spring, jpa, pom.xml

I have this pom

```
    <java.version>7</java.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
     <aspectj.version>1.7.3</aspectj.version>
    <atmosphere.version>2.2.2</atmosphere.version>
    <birt.version>4.2.2</birt.version>
    <c3p0.version>0.9.1.2</c3p0.version>
    <cglib.version>2.2</cglib.version>
    <cors.version>1.3.2</cors.version>
    <dbunit.version>2.4.9</dbunit.version>
    <equalsverifier.version>1.3.1</equalsverifier.version>
    <flyway.version>2.2.1</flyway.version>
    <gson.version>2.2.4</gson.version>
    <hibernate.version>4.2.19.Final</hibernate.version>
    <hibernate.jpamodelgen.version>1.2.0.Final</hibernate.jpamodelgen.version>
    <hibernate.validator.version>4.3.1.Final</hibernate.validator.version>
    <hsqldb.version>2.3.1</hsqldb.version>
    <httpclient.version>4.3.1</httpclient.version>
    <itext.version>2.1.7</itext.version>
    <jackson.version>2.1.5</jackson.version>
    <jadira.version>3.0.0.GA</jadira.version>
    <jasper.version>5.5.0</jasper.version>
    <javax.faces.version>2.2.2</javax.faces.version>
    <jetty.version>8.1.10.v20130312</jetty.version>
    <joda.version>2.3</joda.version>
    <junit.version>4.11</junit.version>
    <log4j.version>1.2.17</log4j.version>
    <mockito.version>1.9.5</mockito.version>
    <poi.version>3.11</poi.version>
    <postgresql.version>9.2-1002-jdbc4</postgresql.version>
    <powermock.version>1.5.2</powermock.version>
    <primefaces.version>5.2</primefaces.version>
    <primefaces.mobile.version>0.9.4</primefaces.mobile.version>
    <primefaces.extensions.version>3.2.0</primefaces.extensions.version>
    <primefaces.themes.version>1.0.10</primefaces.themes.version>
    <selenium.version>2.36.0</selenium.version>
    <servlet-api.version>2.5</servlet-api.version>
    <slf4j.version>1.7.5</slf4j.version>
    <spring.version>3.2.5.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <spring.data.jpa.version>1.4.2.RELEASE</spring.data.jpa.version>
    <spring.integration.version>3.0.1.RELEASE</spring.integration.version>
    <spring.security.version>3.1.4.RELEASE</spring.security.version>
    <xerces.version>2.9.0</xerces.version>
```

And I'm trying to update to java 8 and for the moment I've updated these libraries to go little by little

```
<java.version>8</java.version>

...

<spring.version>4.3.24.RELEASE</spring.version>
<spring.data.jpa.version>2.1.8.RELEASE</spring.data.jpa.version>
<spring.integration.version>4.3.20.RELEASE</spring.integration.version>
<spring.security.version>4.2.12.RELEASE</spring.security.version>
```

The configuration of jpa is fine but it gives me an error:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd">

<repositories base-package="es.abacor.elser.seleccion" />
<repositories base-package="es.abacor.elser.commons" />
```

Error:

```
Unexpected exception parsing XML document from file [/home/usuario/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/elser-seleccion-web/WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/spring/applicationContext-jpa.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.BootstrapMethodError: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/ReactiveTypeDescriptor
```

Someone knows what's happened, and if I have to update some other version in my pom

Answer (score 0):

org.springframework.core.ReactiveTypeDescriptor has been introduced in Spring 5.0 ( [see official doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/ReactiveTypeDescriptor.html)). You have set `<spring.version>4.3.24.RELEASE</spring.version>`.
It seems that your JPA version expect Spring 5.

Similar question and answer here that can help you: [Spring-data-jpa:2.0.3 Compatible Spring Version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51096337/spring-data-jpa2-0-3-compatible-spring-version)

Comment: But if my code is 6 years old, how will Spring 5 expect? If my JPA was with Spring 3 and I want to update it to 4. I do not understand your answer.

Comment: You have specified <spring.data.jpa.version>2.1.8.RELEASE</spring.data.jpa.version>. This version is the latest one and seems to expect a class that is available only in Spring 5.

Comment: Okay. I have to take a minor. Thank you.